# cant see workflow in site solution's and feature's

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I need to deploy my state machine workflow in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2013.

I created a sandbox solution , and I added a state machine workflow.
when I deploy the solution it show this error:

> Error 95  The Project Item "Workflow_CV" cannot be deployed through a Feature in a Sandboxed Solution.

So I turned the propeties of the solution to

> sandboxsolution: False

Then, the solution is deployed and the feature is activated, but I couldn't see neither the feature  or the solution in Site Collection and the workflow doesn't works.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the scope of your solution feature? Make sure you set site URL properly

Comment: the scope of solution feature:site

Comment: is feature marked as hidden?

Comment: Your feature must be WEB scope, if you want to deploy it as a sandbox solutions.

Comment: Acctualy the feature dont comporte the item hidden , so i added it hidden="false" , but it also doesnt show the feature, when i use feature management: It show the feature=> Site: 'SP_WF_WF_Feature' [15/28bb5789-d1aa-4da0-9d8f-a7f23852370d]

Comment: I just restart the machine and it's work